# What should we do in cases where a new query is needed for the DTO class?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, dao, dto

For example, I have a bank application. And I have name, surname, citizenship number and address in my database table. That's why I will have these properties in my Entity Class. But in my DTO class, I have name, surname, citizenship number, address and tax number. And the property named tax number can be pulled from another table with the database function. But I can't add the property named tax ID to my real Entity Class because it comes from another table. So where can I call the database function that pulls the property named "tax number"? Is it at the service tier? Is it somewhere else? I hope you understand.

Comment: It is pretty much unclear what you are asking. Can you provide a code example?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited the question for you. Unfortunately I don't have the code.

Comment: @Backwindow Do you use spring data jpa?

Comment: Yes. I am using Hibernate implementation of the JPA